# Get information about balance of Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I have a task is get information about balance of PayPal account and send it to a list email every month, i wonder how to get information about balance and give me an example? Can you help me, please! Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799712/get-total-of-balance-in-paypal-account

Answer (score 0):

You can also find some [sample code on PayPal's Developer site](http://paypal.github.io/sample-apps/) for the GetBalance API.  There are some samples in various languages. The GetBalance API samples would be under the Classic API/Merchant API's.